# Adding a quotation at the beginning of a book

Tags: titles, quoting

I am using the `book` document format in my Latex book. I am writing a scientific book. I have a cover page (the one with `\maketitle`) and the Table of Contents page(s).

Right after the cover page, I want a blank page (that would be the second cover, that's what it's called, I guess, the one of the verso of the cover page) and then I want a that has a *box* (without any borders, of course) to contain the quotation and be aligned on the middle center of this page. After this, one blank page and the Table of Contents.

I am working on A4 paper ( 210 x 297mm ), and I want this box to be 110mm wide

How can I accomplis this?

Comment: please show us a miniml example of your code, it can help in understanding what you want.

Comment: You might use the `epigraph` package.

Comment: You could use `epigraph`, but you could also just do it manually. It is one-off, after all. That said, as I read your question, you want the quote in the middle of the first page of the ToC. Since this would be inconvenient for readers and is scarcely conventional, I guess that's not what you mean. Note that some classes have extensive support for various kinds of front matter. Whether yours is one of them is worth finding out.

Comment: The flowfram package can break the TOC in the middle of a page.  Tikzpagenodes can make a killer title page.

Comment: Guys, please see my edit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really sure what the problem is ...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\author{John Birdwatch}
\title{coffee is tasty}
\maketitle
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\parbox{110mm}{\blindtext}
\vfill
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Inroduction}
\end{document}
```